# ng-grid: how to interpolate data in table using scope functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I need to display in ng-grid not data fields themselves, but have them interpolated to make some enumerations and error codes into text messages using functions available to the scope.

Assuming that I have typical ng-grid as here http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVm9Y13T53su3BfQ37Hn?p=preview, how I can do that?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to with the available data, and what you want it to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?
http://plnkr.co/edit/mjEQ1HPMj0pAHcG74dgA?p=preview

I created a function to translate the number to a message which is then displayed in the column instead of the actual data value.